# Combining JSON and PHP Copy

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am looking for some help with the following code, for those of you who like a challenge.

At the moment I am using a 3rd party PHP/MySQL application which essentially provides a table for documents.

I have successfully got the following code to lookup my `templates` table and insert into a `clients` table where certain conditions are true, so it selectively inserts relevant documuments, but for field values only.

In my `templates` table I use their document upload function which saves the document as an attachment, when I look on the MySQL database, this is the value that is provided within the `medium-text` field for that column:

```
[
   {
    "name":"ClientFiles\/POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0_wg1t36oh.pdf",
    "usrName":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0.pdf",
    "size":172223,
    "type":"application\/pdf",
    "searchStr":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement, Rev0.pdf,!:sStrEnd"
   }
]
```

And here is the code I am using to lookup, and loop insert records from my template table to client documents table:

```
//create company folder
$folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"]; if (!file_exists($folder)) { mkdir($folder, 0777, true);};


//Add Template Documentation
//step 1 identify which documentation set is required
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";

$rs = CustomQuery($sql);
    $results = $rs;
    while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())

{

//Step 2 correctly name doc reference
if ($row["scope"] == '9001') 
    $docref = $row["9001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '14001') 
    $docref = $row["14001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '18001') 
    $docref = $row["18001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,14001') 
    $docref = $row["914001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,18001') 
    $docref = $row["918001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '14001,18001') 
    $docref = $row["1418001ref"]; 
elseif ($row["scope"] == '9001,14001,18001') 
    $docref = $row["91418001ref"];


//Step 3 insert template documentation into main docs table
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, docref, doctype, doctitle, revision, issuedate, reasonforchange) values('".$values["companypk"]."', '$docref', '$row[doctype]','$row[templatename]','0.1', now(), 'First Draft')";CustomQuery($sql2);


//step 4 copy and rename attachment into main docs table


//step 5 insert duplicate records from 3 and 4 above into document history (child) table

}
```

Ok so here is what I need:

1. I need a JSON Decode for the JSON above to get the filename, in the instance above this would be `POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement, Rev0_wg1t36oh.pdf`
2. I need a PHP Copy code that would take the above file, location is always going to be at the /Templates folder (the example above is from a different area but shows you JSON structure), so copy from /Templates/filename AND then pastes to `$folder/$row["docref"]` - the document reference is dynamic based on a list of values from the templates table
3. I then need to reconstruct the JSON code to update the new filename and location, all other variables within the string will remain constant, this output will then become `$newattachment`, which will be used in step 3 of the code above.

Thanks for reading, and any constructive answers will be appreciated.

Comment: So... [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode), [copy](http://php.net/copy), and [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No thats about right, but need someone to show me how to do example of JSON decode in this instance

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? `json_decode` seems to take your sapmle text just fine: http://codepad.org/U44MOv0z